# Questions regarding socket.io functions

Tags: socket.io

What does socket.on and socket.emit mean? I can't seem to find explanations on the socket.io website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.on` Listen to the socket on a specific keyword. Similar to [JQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
`socket.emit` "sends" a message to that keyword

The following code sends a message to "keyword"

```
socket.emit('keyword', 'Hello!');
```

The following code listens for messages on "keyword"

```
socket.on('keyword', function(res){
    console.log(res)//prints "Hello!"
    socket.emit('keyword', 'Got your message')
})
```

keyword can be any string you want. And both code snippets can be used client and server side.